# linq to sql batch delete

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following DB:
`Posts` which have an `Id`, `Tags` also with `Id`, and `TagsToPosts` table which have `TagsToPosts.PostId => Posts.Id` and `TagsToPosts.TagId => Tags.Id` FK relations.
I need to delete multiple items from `TagsToPosts` in following way.
I'm creating `IList<Tag> newTags` by parsing a string. Each tag have it's name. I want to delete all `TagsToPosts` items pointing to single post (`TagsToPosts.PostId == mypostid`) and which points to `Tag` with name which not in my `newTags`.

For instance I have one post with `Id = 1`, three tags: `1 => "tag1", 2 => "tag2", 3 => "tag3"` And ManyToMany relations table `TagsToPosts`: `1 => 1, 1 => 2, 1 => 3`
So all three tags are linked to my post.
After that I'll create a new `IList<Tag> newList = new List<Tag>()` by parsing a string. `newList` contains: `0 => "tag1", 0 => "tag2"`.
Now I want to remove third relation from table TagsToPosts because my new list of tags doesn't contain tag with name "tag3". So I need to find a difference. I know I can find similar items using JOIN but how to find difference?

I want this to happend in one DB query without iterating over each item to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with LINQ-to-SQL.

LINQ-to-SQL is not good for batch operations - it can't do batch inserts, it can't do batch updates, and it can't do batch deletes.  Every object in your collection is treated individually.  You can do all the operations in one transaction, but there will always be a query for each record.

[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/99054861-2490-4bbb-aa37-f92e68c85020)

A better option is to write a stored procedure that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Linq Except operator?

For example:

```
var toDelete = (from t in TagsToPost
                select t).Except(from nt in newList
                                 select nt, new TagComparer());

class TagComparer: IEqualityComparer<TagsToPosts>
{
    public bool Equals(TagsToPosts x, TagsToPosts y)
    {
         return x.Tag.Equals(y.Tag, CompareOptions.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PLINQO supports batch delete operations without retrieving the entities first.

var delete = from t in TagsToPost
                select t).Except(from nt in newList
                                 select nt, new TagComparer())

context.Tags.Delete(delete);

http://plinqo.com

Answer (score 0):

My solution which lets you make deletions determined by a class field:

```
public static void DeleteByPropertyList<T, R>(List<T> listToDelete, Expression<Func<T, R>> getField, DataContext context) where T : class {
    List<List<string>> partitionedDeletes = listToDelete.Select(d => string.Format("'{0}'", getField.Compile()(d).ToString())).ToList().Partition<string>(2000).ToList();
    Func<Expression<Func<T, R>>, string> GetFieldName = propertyLambda => ((MemberExpression)propertyLambda.Body).Member.Name;
    MetaTable metaTable = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
    string tableName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", metaTable.Model.DatabaseName, metaTable.TableName);
    foreach (List<string> partitionDelete in partitionedDeletes) {
        string statement = "delete from {0} where {1} in ({2})";
        statement = string.Format(statement, tableName, GetFieldName(getField), string.Join(",", partitionDelete));
        context.ExecuteCommand(statement);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Partition<T>(this IList<T> source, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(source.Count / (double)size); i++)
    yield return new List<T>(source.Skip(size * i).Take(size));
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<OrderItem> deletions = new List<OrderItem>();
    // populate deletions
    LinqToSqlHelper.DeleteByPropertyList<OrderItem, long>(deletions, oi => oi.OrderItemId, context);
```

It only works with a single field, but it could be extended to composite fields easily enough.