# How to write a better linq to sql query c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How i can write a query , so that foreach will not use. My current query is :

```
IEnumerable<GuestRSVP> guestrsvps = db.GuestRSVPs.Where(p => p.CeremonyGuestPartyId == CeremonyGuestpartyId);
            foreach (var grsvp in guestrsvps)
            {
                db.GuestRSVPs.DeleteObject(grsvp);
            }
```

How i can delete all objects in a single query, without using foreach loop ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654561/linq-to-sql-batch-delete

Comment: I think this SO question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt

Answer (score 6):

```
var guestrsvps = db.GuestRSVPs
                   .Where(p => p.CeremonyGuestPartyId == CeremonyGuestpartyId);

db.GuestRSVPs.DeleteAllOnSubmit(guestrsvps);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Delete method and pass lambda predicate into. Snippet should look like:

```
db.GuestRSVPs.Delete(p => p.CeremonyGuestPartyId == CeremonyGuestpartyId);
```

[LINQ to SQL Extension: Batch Deletion with Lambda Expression](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2008/03/06/linq-to-sql-extension-batch-deletion-by-lambda-expression.aspx)