# delete multiple rows in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Till now I was deleting a single row by writing:

```
Role role = new Role();
role = context.Roles.SingleOfDefault(p => p.Rolename == rolename);
context.Roles.DeleteOnSubmit(role);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Now I need to delete from Role Permission table all the Permission rules that he had, so I want with the specific RoleId to delete **multiple rows** from RolePermission table (RolePermission table includes RoleId column). Is there any similar way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq to sql batch delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654561/linq-to-sql-batch-delete)

Comment: Why do you instantiate a new `Role` and then just re-assign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching enough on the internet I 've found the answer to my question and I 've found it in stackoverflow. You can find the link below of from the question and the correct answer:
[How to Delete multiple records in Linq to Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452652/how-to-delete-multiple-records-in-linq-to-entity)

Answer (score 3):

You have the `DeleteAllOnSubmit` method:

```
context.RolePermission.DeleteAllOnSubmit(
           context.RolePermission .Where(p=> p.RoleId == role.RoleId));
```

Comment: First of all, it seems that this query would delete multiple columns from Role table, I want to delete multiple rows from RolePermission table using roleid.
And secondly, I 've tried this command but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
Thank you though for your help!

Comment: @L.Achilles fixed typo.

Comment: @L.Achilles did you call save changes after it ?